# Laravel does not read .env file in panel

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel

I've uploaded my Laravel app to a cpanel host . 
The problem is that Laravel does not read the contents of the .env file and show me a "Whoops, looks like something went wrong." page ( twice In one page )
This error is displayed because the program can not receive the APP_KEY variable . can not read .env file at all . I searched a little for this problem, but the solutions did not work . I tried all these:

- 'php artisan cache:clear' command
- 'php artisan config:clear' command
- 'php artisan config:cache' command
- change permission for .env file (755)
- run all 'composer update' , 'composer install' , 'composer dump-autoload' commands
- I did not use env function anywhere
- There are no spaces in the values stored in the env file

But none of the above did not work out.
However, My program runs well in local ( windows ) and there is no problem But it does not run on the server ( cpanel )

note : I realized that when I execute the 'php artisan config:cache' command on server , all cache files are made in 'bootstrap/cache' folder, except for the config.php file
note2 : I uploaded several times in different ways. Once all the files in the folder in the root and the public files in the public_html folder . and once all the files in the public_html folder. Both not working

Does anyone know where the problem is?

[in this time i put all my app files in public_html folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4Udn.jpg)

Comment: How have you uploaded it to cPanel, What is the file structure? 
I assume you have the contents of your public folder now inside the public_html folder and the rest of your files in the root folder?

Comment: I uploaded several times in different ways. Once all the files in the folder in the root and the public files  in the public_html folder . and once all the files in the public_html folder. Both not working

Comment: APP_KEY is first set in .env and read in config/app.php.

Comment: post screen shot of your file tree

Comment: As I said, the problem is not app key at all. The problem is that the .env file is not read. I can set app key in config.php directly . but i want to know why .env file not working . +this is not a real project this is a test on cpanel .

Comment: Are the permissions on the `.env` file correct?

Comment: I even changed the permission to 755.but still not working

Comment: Just make sure your .env file exists in Laravel root folder where artisan file exists

Comment: Yes it is there

Comment: Nothing to mind?
I installed even previous versions of Laravel. But they still had the same problem
Is there a problem with the httpd apache settings or php.ini ok?
If so, which settings should be applied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the `storage/logs/laravel.log` file to get more accurate information.

Make sure the `putenv()` and `getenv()` functions are not disabled In `php.ini`

Comment: Yeah . I contacted my hosting server to enable the `putenv` function for me. It works well now. Thank you buddy

Answer (score -1):

That always happens to me on new sites, so I usually run:

```
chmod 777 storage/ storage/app/ storage/framework/ storage/logs/
chmod 777 storage/ storage/app/ storage/framework/ storage/logs/
chmod 777 storage/framework/cache/ storage/framework/sessions/ storage/framework/views/
chmod 777 bootstrap/cache/
chmod 777 bootstrap/cache/*
chmod 777 storage/logs/laravel.log
```

Note: The last one (laravel.log) does not exist the first time, bun then it is created.

Instead of 777 you could use a more recommended ug+rwx if you first run:
    chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
    chgrp -R www-data storage storage

where www-data is the web server user, it could be apache or httpd

Comment: Thank you but did not solve the problem. Just asking for curiosity :These changes do not affect security?

Comment: These changes *obliterate* security on a shared host. **Do not use 777 on shared hosting.**